# When do you explicitly have to instantiate UINavigationController on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The generic template we use for Navigation looks something like this in applicationDidFinishLoading: in an AppDelegate on the iPhone:

```
    [window addSubview:navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

My question is rather simple. If navController has an IBOutlet, is it instantiated for us already?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making the navController an IBOutlet, you also need to link the outlet to a UINavigationController object in Interface Builder. When the NIB is loaded, all objects in it are instantiated. The IBOutlet simply gives you a pointer to the object automatically instantiated during the process of loading of the NIB.